# How can I detect/observe when third party app launches a full screen process?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I would like to build a helper app for gamers, and to build some extra functionality I would like to observe/time certain third party games behaviors, more specifically when the game actually launches the full screen process.

**For example:** my app is a system tray app, the game has a "launcher" app with lobby and menu screens. Once the game launches the extra process, usually OS X will switch resolutions (optionally) and my App would be notified somehow. Then I can start a timer. Once game match finishes, either the process is closed, or the game is not full screen anymore, my app gets a second notification and I can stop the timer.

Are there official Apple APIs that provide any way to observe/poll for the app going full screen and/or launch additional windows that I can reliably assume it's the actual game screen?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23844148/12484

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you're going to find a completely comprehensive solution. There are many ways for apps to achieve a full-screen experience and most don't provide a notification about that fact.

A full-screen app can modify the `presentationOptions` of `NSApplication` to hide the Dock and menu bar. Another app can use key-value observing to monitor its application object's `currentSystemPresentationOptions` property, which will reflect the current system status.

A full-screen app can capture the displays (although Apple discourages this technique). You can try to detect this by calling `CGDisplayIsCaptured()`, although it's been deprecated since 10.9 with no replacement. It may be possible that, if you register a callback with `CGDisplayRegisterReconfigurationCallback()`, you'll get called when something captures the display. However, capturing the display is sort of *about* preventing other processes from noticing such changes, so maybe not. In that case, you'd have to poll. You might also poll for the current display mode; changing the mode is the primary reason why a game would capture the display in the first place.

A full-screen game could also just create a borderless window the size of the screen and set its window level to be in front of the Dock and menu bar (and other apps' windows). There's not really a notification about this. You could detect it using the `CGWindowList` API, but you would have to poll. For example, you could call `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID)` and iterate through the dictionaries looking for one the size of the screen and at a window level above `kCGStatusWindowLevel`.

(You might be able to use the Accessibility API to get a notification when the frontmost window changes, so you'd only have to poll when that happens.)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot observe a notification if there is none. So firstly you need to know if the app you want to observe is actually sending a notification that is observable. You cannot 'hook' into other apps without their planned consent.