# macOS programmatically show system menu bar

Tags: swift, macos

I'm working on a menu bar app that opens a popover view. I'd like to display the popover when the app launches. This works great if the foreground app is not in full screen mode.

But, if the foreground app is in fullscreen mode, the popover just floats in the middle of the screen (apparently since the menu bar is not visible). Ideally, I'd like a way to automatically show the menu bar when the app launches.

Alternatively, is there a way to at least detect if the foreground app is full screen so I can disable opening the popover in that case?

Here's the current code:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
    var popover = NSPopover()

    @objc func togglePopover(sender: AnyObject?) {
        if popover.isShown {
            closePopover(sender: sender)
        } else {
            showPopover(sender: sender)
        }
    }

    func showPopover(sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let button = statusItem.button {
            popover.show(relativeTo: button.bounds, of: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
        }
    }

    func closePopover(sender: AnyObject?) {
        popover.performClose(sender)
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        statusItem.button?.image = NSImage(named: "MenuIcon")
        statusItem.button?.action = #selector(AppDelegate.togglePopover(sender:))
        popover.contentViewController = PopoverViewController(nibName: "PopoverView", bundle: nil)
        showPopover(sender: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: In what circumstance is your app launched while another app is active and full screen?

Comment: @TheNextman it could be launched via spotlight or launchpad.  Also, I have a custom URL scheme registered, so it could be launched directly from another app in full screen mode (most likely a browser).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56526010/233944